# Make sense of the grids

Tags: knowledge, visual, grid-deduction

- *Make sense of the following two grids using the visual clues.*
- *Both grids have a common theme.*
- *What do they say?*

---

***GRID 1***
[image]

---

***GRID 2***
[image]

---

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two grids hide two messages:

> **HASTA LA VISTA BABY**
>
>  and
>
>  **SNAP OUT OF IT**

These are both...

> ...famous **movie quotes**, from *Terminator 2: Judgment Day* and *Moonstruck*, respectively. The names of the movies are clued in the pictures associated with the grids (Judgment + Day / Moon + Struck).

The technique to produce the final answers involves...

> ...folding the grids along the dark lines, so that the right-hand set of squares is folded over to the left, and the bottom set of squares is folded up to the top. All letters then fall into the right spaces to spell out the quotes in full, with each word on a separate line.
>
>  [image: Folded grids]

It's also worth noting from a puzzle design point of view that...

> ...all the letters in the section folded horizontally have *vertical symmetry*, and all those in the section folded vertically have *horizontal symmetry* - this pleasingly means that no further manipulation of the letters is required to make them look their normal selves even when just folded over!