# Self-reflections

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction

Copying is a form of praise (some say).
And I will be honest for a change; I am just a thief.
And as such:

- I am lazy (yellow)
- I (mis)interpret the rules whenever convenient.
  (red)
- Things got more complicated (for a thief, things are only easy on moonless nights)

[image: imageof the grid]

That should not prevent you from decoding my message, especially if you know

[ the answer ]

Hint- If the direct approach is preferred

> The title is in plural, it does not (only) refer to reflections of the thief, it refers to a multitude of reflections.

Hint- Following the story

> "I (mis)interpret the rules" So the rules are made somewhere else.
>  Probably rules about (letter) grids and/or 'self reflections'. were used by someone (before this puzzle was created).
>  One could try to find those rules.

Extra hints

> If you stand before a mirror, you are real, the mirror image is not **+** you see the mirror image, not yourself. So: find the original, remove the reflection. This may not be easy if there are multiple mirrors.

> Start with self-reflections of the white squares, they have nothing special mentioned.

Note: I am not happy with my [grid-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) tag; it does not fit well,
also 'letter' is not a very good fit, maybe [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) (added by oAlt, thx!) should be the only tag. (Suggestions, probably after the puzzle is solved, are welcome.)

Comment: For those who might be interested, I think that references to 'copying' here suggest that this puzzle is inspired by or based off [this earlier one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/117929/60644), posted just four hours before. I further suspect that for yellow cells, rot13(jura tevqf ner ersyrpgrq, gurfr yrggref erznva va gurve bevtvany bevragngvba.) I do not know what the reds do, and I have not been able to formalise any rules myself just yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Final Grid:

> `MAKE S`
>  `ENSE O`
>  `F THE` 
>  `GRIDS` 
>  `BY CHA`
>  `NDA777`

Rules:

> Letters can only be flipped over their symmetrical axis:
>
> 1. H,I can be flipped to any square
> 2. S,N can be flipped along the diagonal axis
> 3. B,C,E,K can be flipped across the horizontal axis (up and down)
> 4. A can be flipped across the vertical axis (<->)
> 5. F,G can't be flipped at all (aren't symmetrical)

With the following exceptions:

> 1. Red Squares can be flipped to squares regardless of symmetry. That's how W -> M and L -> 7 (misinterpreted rules)
>
>    Yellow squares stay in place (lazy)

My only problem (and potentially a mistake/something I'm missing):

> The original puzzle referenced is by chandanr777 not chanda777, so the nr is inexplicably gone. Might be explained by the thief part, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: In reference to the red squares, I believe that they may be allowed to move based on rotational symmetry instead of reflective symmetry, therefore "misinterpreting the rules".